# How to use foreach statement to loop through Faroo json search engine results?

Tags: php, foreach, search-engine

I do not quite understand the parameters I need to use for a foreach statement to work on this query.

Any idea why this foreach does not work? sample faroo query:
 http://www.faroo.com/api?q=%27elephants%27&start=1&length=10&l=en&src=web&f=json&jsoncallback=mycallback&key=y3EVs8B2ntbxXrmZWpBTDBueayA_&rlength=0

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

if ($_POST['query'])
{
    $query = urlencode("'{$_POST['query']}'");
    $fullUri = 'http://www.faroo.com/api?q='.$query.'&start=1&length=10&l=en&src=web&f=json&jsoncallback=mycallback&key=y3EVs8B2ntbxXrmZWpBTDBueayA_&rlength=0';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullUri);
    echo $fullUri;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    $js = json_decode($data);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($js -> results as $item)
    {
        $Faroo[$i] = "<a href=\"{$item->url}\"> 
        {$item->title}</a>faroo  
        <p>$item->kwic}</p>";    
        $i++;

    }

    echo $Faroo[3];

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you use before the `foreach` to process `$js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `jsoncallback` parameter from the request... what's being returned isn't valid `JSON`. Removing this parameter fixes the issue.

I'd check into [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) if you run into issues with `JSON` in the future- it can be very helpful!

Comment: With the jsoncallback parameter the data is JSON-P [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), where the JSON data is embedded in JavaScript code to support cross-domain requests from JavaScript within the browser.